# How to center contents of an absolute div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm using font awesome library. I would like to put **horizontally center** the Arrow icon. And DIVs must be **absolute** position.

I use this code but it doesn't work.

```
.arrow {
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetdemiray/z6dw4pno/1/)**

Comment: Please include your code *in the question* itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: Move `left: 0; right: 0;` to the parent div which is positioned absolutely.

Comment: If you really want the parent `div` to be absolute, then give it an appropriate width. Technically, the arrow is centered already, because you gave the parent `div` `text-align:center;`.

Comment: @gvee The title is misleading, the question is not really about centering an `absolute` positioned div, but its contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `width:100%` in absolute `div`

```
.home .center {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top:30px;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
```

**Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6dw4pno/2/)**

Comment: I forgot only "width:100%" . Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is working example. You can delete ***.arrow*** css rule because it does nothing.

```
.home {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

.home .center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    top:30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML Code:

```
<div class="home">
   <div class="center">
     <a class="arrow fa fa-long-arrow-down fa-3x" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.home {
     margin: 0 auto;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-width: 960px;
 }

.home .center {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top:30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.arrow {    
}
```

Comment: `position: fix;` huh?! I guess you meant `fixed`.

Comment: .home is relative. it must be absolutely positioned. I solved problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work,try it.

```
   .home {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

.center {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    top:30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.arrow
     left: 0;
    right: 0;
```

As an explanation why it works: well,the wrapper div must be absolute,and its content has to be relative to position what is inside of the wrapper as you please.In this way,will be easier for you if you want to add further relative divs

Answer (score 1):

I just changed into your CSS, and it works fine.

```
.home {
    margin: 0 auto;
 }

.home .center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.arrow
   margin: 0 auto;    
}
```

Cheers!